# WCF service (not released by iis) give no response to asihttprequest in iOS App

Tags: ios, wcf, iis

In LAN,there is a WCF service with the uri `"http://172.10.50.232:18090/HB/LocateOnRoadService.svc"`

My app use ASIFormDataRequest to send a request.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.10.50.232:18090/HB/LocateOnRoadService.svc"];
self.locationRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\
                         <s:Body>\
                         <LocateOnRoadWithResolution xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\
                         <mapX>12313</mapX>\
                         <mapY>1321</mapY>\
                         <resolution>5</resolution>\
                         </LocateOnRoadWithResolution>\
                         </s:Envelope>"];
NSLog(@"%@",soapMessage);
NSString *strLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];

[self.locationRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

//[self.locationRequest addRequestHeader:@"Host" value:@"172.10.50.232:18090"];

[self.locationRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml;charset=utf-8"];
[self.locationRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:strLength];
[self.locationRequest addRequestHeader:@"SOAPAction" value:@"http://tempuri.org/ILocateOnRoadService/LocateOnRoadWithResolution"];

[self.locationRequest appendPostData:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[self.locationRequest setDelegate:self];
[self.locationRequest setPersistentConnectionTimeoutSeconds:5.0];
[self.locationRequest startAsynchronous];
```

the Delegate method `- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request`

can be called ,but the `[request responseData]` always give NULL.

What's the problem,looking forward to some help,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\
                     <s:Body>\
                     <LocateOnRoadWithResolution xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\
                     <mapX>12313</mapX>\
                     <mapY>1321</mapY>\
                     <resolution>5</resolution>\
                     </LocateOnRoadWithResolution>\
                     </s:Body>\
                     </s:Envelope>"];
```

the soap message should be complete.
And the quest address declared by wsdl is `http://172.10.50.232:18090/`,not `http://172.10.50.232:18090/HB/LocateOnRoadService.svc`